# Difference between BE per nucleon and seperation energy of nucleon

Tags: nuclear-physics

What is the difference between Binding energy per nucleon and seperation energy of nucleon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding energy is the energy which would be required to disassemble a nucleus completely into protons and neutrons.  The binding energy *per nucleon* is a quick way to compare binding energies between nuclei with very different masses.

The nucleon separation energy is the energy required to remove one single nucleon. For element $Z$ with mass number $A$, the separation energy is the mass difference between the ground state $^A Z$ and the separated states, $^{ (A-1)}Z+\rm n$ for neutron separation, and $^{(A-1)}(Z-1)+\rm p$ for proton separation.

The separation energy may or may not be close to the binding energy per nucleon. The separation energy is subject to coincidences in ground-state energies, pairing effects, etc.  A nucleus with negative nucleon separation energy is said to be on (or beyond) the “drip line,” because it can release energy by letting a nucleon just fall off of it.  But a drip-line nucleus does not, in general, have a negative *total* binding energy, nor therefore a negative BE per nucleon.